# Add all users in shared roster in ejabberd

Tags: ejabberd

Trying to setup ejabberd to get the presence of other users. What known so far, If I want to know the status (Presence) of some other users than the one that are in his own roster list in ejabberd. But I don't want to maintain a roster list for every user and instead I am using mod_shared_roster, so that anyone can know anyone's status. So I make a common group and did this.

[image]

After doing this.

1. When I go to a specific person's roster, it still shows nothing. Am i
   missing something?
2. How wise it would to add everyone in everyone's roster (although I am not able to do it) instead of added individual users to roster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shared Rosters are dynamic. It means that the relevant entry to users roster are added dynamically at retrieval time. It means that when a roster is retrieved by a user, ejabberd merges user's standard contacts and his shared roster contacts before delivering it.

The users can still have a standard roster, for example with contacts from another server and there roster will be unmodified.

So, it is normal that you do not see any change to user roster in ejabberd database. However, when you connect with that user account, you will see that the roster is correct and contains the contact from the shared roster.

While it is not recommended to have huge user rosters, you will not occur a huge performance penalty when relying on shared roster to populate user's roster, as this feature is supposed to be used for moderately sized corporate servers.

Comment: sir, does standard roster has edge in terms of performance over shared roster? I mean when the user set grows , will retrieval of presence will take  more time than standard roster?

Comment: It depends on many parameters, especially the number of users served on your domain, number of different shared roster, etc. But generally, if the feature you want to use match the shared roster use case, then that's what you should use.

Comment: @MickaëlRémond can you give me some suggestion for following scenario : We have two types of user A and B, Now all the users of type B should be able to chat with type A. Is it possible to use only one shared roster group for all the users? And is it possible to bypass the roster authorization between two users? please give me some guidance for this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: In XMPP, roster is only about presence. You can chat with anyone you like.